# Set session cookie in login using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I am using AJAX to login to the server. For API calls the server uses session authentication. How do I set the browser session from a login response?

```
$http({ method: 'POST',
            url: API_URL+'/signin',
            data: $scope.loginData
        }).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          //I want to set the browser session here
          // In postman I see a cookie which contains sessionId
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log(data);
        });
```

It's a cross domain request as the server allows that

Comment: cookies are automatically set even with ajax login. I was not setting `withCredentials` for authenticated calls which is required for CORS access.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [library like this one](https://github.com/khaliid/happy-cookies.js) to set a cookie and get it everytime you need like this

```
$.setCookie("sessionId",value);

$.getCookie("sessionId"); // returns value
```